# How do I remove the padding from the main div in Plotly Dash?

Tags: css, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to remove the padding from the main Dash div that encapsulates all content. It has no className so I can't affect it with CSS.

In the image, you can see in the Inspector pane that the div with id `_dash-app-content` contains the div with the problematic padding.

How do I remove this padding?

[image: The purple margin is the padding from the main div]

Comment: Did the solutions solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set the padding and margin equal to 0 as follows:

```
app.layout = html.Div(       # <------ main Div
    children=[
        html.H1("Hello World!")
    ],
    style={
        "padding": "0px",    #<---------- here
        "margin": "0px"      #<---------- here
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#child_combinator) selector:

```css
#_dash-app-content > div {
   padding: 0;
}
```

Optionally, you could also use the specified style attribute of the element.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#_dash-app-content div[style="background-color: red;"] {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="_dash-app-content">
  <div style="background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```